# Boost Zlib Filters error

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use the Boost Zlib Filters library but having some issues. I'm compiling with Code Blocks and GNU GCC. Here's the sample code I'm testing with

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;

    ifstream file("hello.z", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    copy(in, cout);

    return 0;
}
```

Within the Code Blocks linker settings I have linked z, boost_system, boost_iostreams.

For some reason when I run the code I'm getting the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::iostreams::zlib_error> >'
  what():  zlib error

Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)  execution time : 0.136 s
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? What error code does that exception hold?

Comment: When I compile the debugger doesn't throw an error. Sorry i'm new to c++ i'm not sure what you mean by your second question.

Comment: You should probably read up a little on exceptions in c++ and on using a debugger. a) Debugger has nothing to do with the compilation. You would run the compiled and linked executable in the debugger, telling it to break when an error occurs. Then you would examine the state of your program at that point, to figure out more details about the problem. b) You'd catch the exception thrown (`zlib_error`)[http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html#zlib_error_constructor]. This class has a method called `error()`.

Comment: ... You can use this method to obtain an [error code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html#constants) which will tell you a little more about why it failed.

Comment: There could be trailing byte(s) in the input stream. Have you tried using a file generated using `zlib_compressor`?